# create standalone app with EMGU

Tags: c#, user-interface, emgucv

I have been using EMGU for a while now a couple of projects. Everything I have done so far is based on the examples, CameraCapture in particular). This has worked well for me but I am would like to package up the application so it can be used but others and it will require the user selecting a feed, saving results, etc. I would like to have a complete user interface but most of the examples are single purpose with no UI.

Are there any good examples out with of a standalone EMGU based app with a menu driven user interface? Thanks